# AwesomeWM on Raspberry Pi "Error Nil at Screen Connect"

Tags: awesome-wm

I have Arch installed on my raspberry pi and am trying to use AwesomeWM. It works with the basic config, but when I try to use my modified version of copycats copland theme I get this error on the following line.

```
"Error Nil at Screen Connect"

-- Create a wibox for each screen and add it
awful.screen.connect_for_each_screen(function(s) beautiful.at_screen_connect(s) end)
-- }}}
```

I had a similar issue with i3 on it with raspbian and I think the issue is due to the pi not having a lvds display. Is there anyway to fix this issue on the pi? This config works just fine on my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue last night. There's some issue with the lain, noted [here](https://github.com/lcpz/lain/issues/387) that is resulting in every single awesome copycat theme save the last being broken. While there are solutions are that issue on updating the version of Glib, I found it much simpler to revert to an earlier checkout of lain.

To do this, cd into the lain folder. Then run

```
git checkout -b SAFE_COMMIT_HASH
```

I personally ran

```
git checkout -b 35856d49a249cdfff09439fde73351b12ed8576c
```

I chose a commit in January to be safe because it was late and I wanted to be done.

All I had to do after this was reboot my Awesome shell and everything went back to working order.